# How to make an NSCalendar week begin on Monday instead of Sunday

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, nscalendar

When i try to make so that the current weeks date show up in the log (Monday to Sunday) it's like a week starts with a Sunday.
For example:
This week is wee 38.
Yesterday it was 20th of September. My code did show the days from Monday to Sunday correct.
But today (21th of September) my log shows next weeks dates (week 39) when it's still week 38.

My code:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *myCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *currentComps = [myCalendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:currentDate];
int thisWeeksNumber = currentComps.weekOfYear;
NSLog(@"1  %d", thisWeeksNumber);

[currentComps setWeekday:2];

NSDate *firstDayOfTheWeek = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:currentComps];
NSDate *secondDayOfTheWeek = [self dateByAddingDays:1 toDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];
NSDate *thirdDayOfTheWeek = [self dateByAddingDays:2 toDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];
NSDate *fourthDayOfTheWeek = [self dateByAddingDays:3 toDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];
NSDate *fifthDayOfTheWeek = [self dateByAddingDays:4 toDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];
NSDate *sixthDayOfTheWeek = [self dateByAddingDays:5 toDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];
NSDate *seventhDayOfTheWeek = [self dateByAddingDays:6 toDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];

NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
myDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSString *firstStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *secondStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:secondDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *thirdStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:thirdDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *fourthStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:fourthDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *fifthStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:fifthDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *sixthStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:sixthDayOfTheWeek];
NSString *seventhStr = [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:seventhDayOfTheWeek];

NSLog(@"\n %@ \n %@ \n %@ \n %@ \n %@ \n %@ \n %@", firstStr, secondStr, thirdStr, fourthStr, fifthStr, sixthStr, seventhStr);   
}
```

And my NSDate Method:

```
- (NSDate*)dateByAddingDays:(NSInteger)days toDate:(NSDate *)date
{
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps.day = days;

return [calendar dateByAddingComponents: comps toDate: date options: 0];
}
```

This should display week 38 all days but it display next week dates because it's sunday. 
(as i'm writing this it's week 38 and is 21th of September)

Comment: [myCalendar setFirstWeekday:1];

Comment: I added it to my code, but nothing happened. Got any other ideas?

Answer (score 10):

You need to call [setFirstWeekday:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/setFirstWeekday:) with a `NSUInteger` parameter value of `2` (Sunday is `1`)

```
[myCalendar setFirstWeekday:2];
```

Comment: Well done.  I was confused by the title of the post.  (which should read, How to make the week begin on Monday, rather than Sunday).

Comment: Sunday it's also the default for en-US culture. (I'm not 100% certain as to when localization is applied to NSCalendar)

Comment: The thing is that i display next weeks days, not the current week (because it's sunday, yesterday it works like a charm!)

Comment: @Dridia It's not at all clear what you're trying to archive here. I'll recommend you familiarize yourself with the API: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470

Comment: The above code shows week 39s all days, monday to sunday when the current week is 38. The thing is that when it's sunday (like today) the code thinks that it's a new week and shows me monday-sunday for week 39 when it's week 38. I tried the above code yesterday (saturday) and it worked fine. it showed the days of week 38 and NOT 39.

Comment: The first day of the week, and with it the week numbers, are locale dependent. You get different results in the USA and the UK. That's because it _is_ actually a different week.